# gulp : live reloading redirect to tomcat7 home page

Tags: gulp, jhipster

When I run `gulp`, it opens the web browser with the url : **localhost:9000**.
But instead of displaying my webapp, it displays the tomcat homepage.

How can I force gulp to display my webapp page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that your app has a context path in Tomcat.
Let's say your webapp is at `/myapp`, edit your `gulp/serve.js` file and add a startPath to browserSync options:

```
browserSync({
    open: true,
    startPath: '/myapp',
    port: config.port,
    server: {
        baseDir: config.app,
        middleware: proxies
    }
});
```

Comment: I m using gulp when I run my app from Eclipse. I am not sure if I need a startPath (I have tried, but I am getting a 404). One other weird thing is that when I run gulp, it update my index.html by removing the last dependencies(ng-table css and jd) I have added.

Comment: It's the expected behavior, you're not supposed to insert dependencies manually into your index.html, you must use `bower install <something> --save` and gulp will inject the required files according to the `main` property in the bower.json of the added dependency.

Comment: What do you mean by "I run my app from Eclipse"?

Comment: In Eclipse I run byt right clicking on myAppApplication.java and "run application"

Comment: I have installed ngtable with bower, but if I don't add the CSS and JS to index.html I am getting this error at runtime : Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngTable' is not available!

Comment: running gulp did inject the dependency, my bad . But localhost:9000 leads to tomcat7 homepage.  Grunt used to work (if I remember well).

Comment: OK so if you run it like this from Eclipse, it means that you run embedded tomcat so I don't see why you would have a context path unless you configured server.contextPath property in your application.yml. What do you mean by "my webapp page"? Which url?

Comment: wWhen I run from eclipse, the url is localhost:8080. For me : webapp page is the home page of my web app, not the homepage of tomcat. I have not configured context path.

Comment: So clarify your question, when do you see the homepage of tomcat?

Comment: when I run gulp. Gulp open a web browser with the url localhost:9000. I have the tomcat homepage displaying at this url.

Comment: Is it the same when you run your app with `mvn` instead of running the main class from Eclipse?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107881/discussion-between-gael-marziou-and-user1260928).